# How can I use Entity Framework to connect to 2 databases with different schemas from one VS solution?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This has nothing to do with 2 different connection strings to 2 servers with the same schema.

Here's our challenge, which is not off the beaten path.

We have our EF model to match our dev server's SQL server schema. The code using the model is deployed to the dev server's app server.

A previous version of the code and EF model has been deployed to our staging server. The EF model on staging is different to the EF model in dev because it was created some weeks ago and the dev model has more functionality.

Just to be clear, say in the dev model we need to read from a SQL DB column that we added into the code after we deployed to staging. This EF model will not connect to staging because the column is "missing".

Now I want to write code that uses EF to move data from dev to staging. It seems like I should be able to have 2 EF models and use one model to read from dev and another model to write to staging. How do I implement this?

Comment: For me it is not clear what the problem here, but looks like you need a migrations mechanism to keep schema updated. Migration of data is the separate question...

Comment: The problem is using a single codebase to talk to two different SQL DB schemas. The migration mechanism is in place but all that does is ensure deployed code (ie EF model) matches a deployed schema. It does not allow un-deployed code to talk to a deployed DB schema that uses a previous version of the EF model.

Comment: ```Now I want to write code that uses EF to move data from dev to staging.``` If this will be only for 1 run, why you wont to use just simple ORM, like dapper, to move your data from one schema to another?

Comment: It's not one run. The code will form a "publish" button that allows the user to push data to production, adding to options in features that has previously been deployed

Comment: You will need to keep two completely different sets of models and two contexts, not mix the two, point each at the different databases, and write the code to transform / update from the one to the other.